# How can I remove the word chapter from the appendix title in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

Currently, my table of contents looks like this:

[image]

I am happy with my chapter titles, but I want to remove the word chapter after appendix so instead of it reading "APPENDIX CHAPTER A: Extra Stuff," I want it to read "APPENDIX A: Extra Stuff."

Someone on this forum previously helped me add the word chapter at the beginning of each chapter before the number. I want to keep the chapters as they are, but remove the word chapter from the appendix.

Here is part of my current code:

```
\usepackage {tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER } % put this before the number
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em} % extra space for number and pre-name
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{. } % put period after chapter number and space

\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}

\tableofcontents
```

Thank you for the help! Let me know if you need anything clarified.

Comment: Please complete your code ro a MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that.

Comment: Uou can use the `appendix` package, with the following options: 
    `\usepackage[toc,page, title, titletoc]{appendix}`